# Rewrite target URL to header value

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

Can API Management rewrite a backend URL to be the value of a request header? For example, if I have a request originating with header `X-ProxyTarget: https://api.ipify.org/`, and I send it to `https://my-api.azure-api.net/proxy` then can a policy (or combination of policies) on inbound (or backend) forward the request to `https://api.ipify.org`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the set-backend-service policy in the inbound section. This policy updates the backend URL as provided and read the input header value to set the url.
Sample Code:

```
<set-backend-service base-url="@(context.Request.Headers.GetValueOrDefault("X-ProxyTarget","http://my-api.net"))" />
```

References : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-transformation-policies#SetBackendService